# unit-test with HTTP request returns Promise { <pending> }

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, unit-testing, axios

I am using axios mock adapter to mock HTTP request to test my function. After I defined the behaviour for the function, and then I created an instance of the class to call the function, the result is

```
**Promise { <pending> }**,
```

what is the problem? how can I return the value I defined?

Here is my code:

**UserService.js**

```
export default class UserService {
  getUserInfo = userId => {
    const params = {
      userId,
    };

    return axios
      .get('https://www.usefortesting.com', {
        params: { userId: params },
      })
      .then(response => response.data.userInfo)
      .catch(error => error);
  };
}
```

**UserService.test.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import UserService from './UserService';
import MockAdapter from 'axios-mock-adapter';

describe('testing', () => {
  let axiosMock;
  const Info = {
    userInfo: {
      id: '123',
      name: 'omg',
    },
  };
  beforeEach(function() {
    axiosMock = new MockAdapter(axios);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    axiosMock.reset();
    axiosMock.restore();
  });

  it('testing', () => {
    axiosMock
      .onGet('https://www.usefortesting.com', {
        params: { userId: 'user_1' },
      })
      .reply(200, Info);
    let userService = new UserService();
    let response = userService.getUserInfo('user_1');
    console.log(response);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to await for response in your test. Either use callbacks or async/await as shown below.
Your test should be like this:

```
it('testing', async () => {  // notice async here
  axiosMock
    .onGet('https://www.usefortesting.com', {
      params: { userId: 'user_1' },
    })
    .reply(200, Info);
  let userService = new UserService();
  let response = await userService.getUserInfo('user_1');  // notice await here
  console.log(response);
});
```

#### OR

```
it('testing', () => {
  ...
  userService.getUserInfo('user_1').then(response => {
    console.log(response);
  });
});
```

You can check [this link](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-async) on jest docs for more examples.

---

Also there is error in your `getUserInfo()` method, in params you are passing an object for `userId` but you need to pass string or int. What you should do is:

```
return axios.get('https://www.usefortesting.com', {
    params: { userId: params.userId },
})...
```

#### OR

```
return axios.get('https://www.usefortesting.com', {
    params,
})...
```

Comment: Hi, Vaibhav, I used the method you provided, and then return something like this:   response:
   { status: 404,
     config:
      { transformRequest: [Object],
        transformResponse: [Object],
        timeout: 0,
        xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
        xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
        maxContentLength: -1,
        validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
        headers: [Object],
        method: 'get',
        params: [Object],
        url: 'https://www.usefortesting.com',
        data: undefined },
     data: undefined }, data here is still undefined

Comment: params in your `getUserInfo` method in `UserService` is incorrect. Take a look again at the params you are passing. What you should do is: `return axios.get('https://www.usefortesting.com', { params: params })` or just `return axios.get('https://www.usefortesting.com', { params })`